# OrientGraphFactory Pool vs Network Connection Pool

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I've recently started using the new OrientGraphFactory in OrientDB 2.1 and it's been great for the most part.

I'm using scala, and doing it like so:

```
lazy val orientFactory = new OrientGraphFactory(url, username, password).setupPool(minConnections, maxConnections)
```

When I need a new database instance, I simply do:

```
val graph = orientFactory.getTx.asInstanceOf[TransactionalGraph]
```

This all seems to be working well, but I'm running into some issues at high load. I'm suspecting that perhaps I need to do some extra work with the Network Connection Pool, as specified in the OrientDB Docs: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Performance-Tuning.html

The documentation suggests setting the network connection pool like so:

> database = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("remote:localhost/demo");
>   database.setProperty("minPool", 2);
>   database.setProperty("maxPool", 5);
>
> database.open("admin", "admin");

What I'm wondering is whether the OrientGraphFactory pool also serves as a network pool of sorts, creating a network connection for each database instance. Is this the case? Or do I need to additionally setup the network connection pool?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network pool uses this setting to setup the maximum number of connections:

```
OGlobalConfiguration.CLIENT_CHANNEL_MAX_POOL.setValue( 500 );
```

The default is 100.